# Multi Bloc Provider Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

I have several cubits working in my application, but for the cubit to work it always needs to be injected into the MyApp Main of my application, is there any way to concentrate the Cubit / Bloc instances without having to fill the APP with code?

```
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => AuthenticationCubit(
                secureStorage: secureStorage,
                socialAuthenticationCubit: socialAuthenticationCubit),
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => RegisterAccountCubit(
                secureStorage: secureStorage,
                socialAuthenticationCubit: socialAuthenticationCubit,
                uploadRepository: uploadRepository),
          ),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => TermsCubit()),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => EmailVerifyCubit(SecureStorage())),
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => AccountProfileCubit(accountRepository,
                  uploadRepository, secureStorage, communityRepository)),
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) =>
                  ForgotPasswordCubit(authenticationRepository, secureStorage)),
          BlocProvider(create: (context) => PreferenceCubit(SecureStorage())),
        ],
        child: Container(
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Inmigra App',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: primaryColor,
            ),
            localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
            supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
            locale: _locale,
            home: const SplashScreen(),
            builder: EasyLoading.init(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: you can create a variable for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block mode management uses the inheritance property and you cannot call a block on a page that you have not introduced in the main root.
So you must follow the standard structure and always introduce bloc in the main root

Comment: Got it, i.e. will I have to actually do the cubit/bloc injections in my main, even if it's over 100?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class that returns `MultiBlocProvider` and takes an argument `Widget<child>` that you use inside `MultiBlocProvider`.

```
class MyBlocProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyBlocProvider({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => SomeBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AnotherBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

then in your `App` class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MyBlocProvider(
        child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'title',
      home: HomePage(),
    ));
  }
}
```